# Can all probability distributions be represented by the probability density function?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

**Informally**, I understand pdfs as the "shape" of relative probabilities in continuum of range space of an RV scaled down to have an integral over $(- \infty, \infty )$ equal to one

Can we then theoretically prove that all possible relative probability densities can be represented by such a function / "shape"?

One way I've been able to **formalize** this question is as follows:

Let $X$ be a random variable.

Given a function $r(x_1, x_2)$ which represents relative probability of the event $X = x_1$ relative to that of event $X = x_2$ where $x_1, x_2 \in range(X)$, can we come up with a PDF $f$ such that $f(x_1)/f(x_2) = r(x_1, x_2)$?

$r$ will have the following properties which might be useful in proving this:

1. $r(x_1, x_2)$ is defined only when the event $[X = x_2]$ is not an impossible event
2. $r(x_1, x_2) = \frac{1}{r(x_2, x_1)}$ provided $r(x_2, x_1) \neq 0$
3. $r(x, y)r(y, z) = r(x, z)$

Assume that the the range of the random variable does not have discrete points. It may be a union of ranges $(a, b)$, $(a, b]$, $[a, b)$, $[a, b]$ where $a \neq b$

Answer (score 1):

In the usual sense: no. A discrete random variable for instance has no probability density in the usual sense.

In a broader sense: yes. Given any CDF, the distributional derivative of that CDF (in the sense of distribution theory, not probability theory) is a PDF, in a loose sense. For example, the "probability density" of a discrete random variable is a convex combination of Dirac delta functions at different points.

Incidentally, your $r$ formalism has lots of subtle issues, in particular "impossible event" is much more badly defined than you would expect. Moreover PDFs are extremely non-unique, so you will need to specify some "selection criterion" to pick one. A starting point for such a criterion is continuity at all Lebesgue points of the CDF, but there are still problems at boundaries (for example there is not really a well-defined value for the PDF of an exponential random variable at $x=0$).

Comment: I understand that there's a correspondence between PDFs and CDFs, but the argument isn't convincing enough because my question then becomes if every possible probability distribution can be represented by a CDF. Basically I want to find if PDFs and CDFs are indeed good representations of probability distributions of real (and possible) phenomena

Comment: I'll add "continuous" to my question to avoid the discussion from going in the other direction of how PMFs may be represented as PDFs

Comment: @PeeyushKushwaha CDFs (in the usual sense of the term) can indeed represent any probability distribution (for finitely many variables). And there is an analogous procedure for dealing with infinitely many variables, which arises in the theory of stochastic processes. Trying to pin down this "impossible event" notion is just going to lead to frustration with minimal insight.

Comment: @PeeyushKushwaha By the way, merely filtering out a discrete part does not make the random variable continuous in the usual sense; there are so-called singular distributions which have continuous CDFs but do not have a PDF in the usual sense. One of these is called the Cantor distribution, which is informally the uniform distribution on the Cantor set.

Comment: ah, I see your point now about "impossible events", since if I were to say that impossible events are the events with probability = 0, but it's always true for a uniform RV X on range $(0, 1)$  that $P[X = 0.1] = 0$. But at the same time the relative probabilities of any two points in that range would still be 1.

Comment: @PeeyushKushwaha That's right. In the continuous setting you want to say something like "$X=x$ is impossible if there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $P(X \in (x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon))=0$", but even then you run into trouble with boundaries (in this definition, if $U$ is a uniform random variable on $(0,1)$, then $U=1$ and $U=0$ are possible; do you want that?) Singular distributions that I mentioned make this even worse (discrete distributions, or mixed distributions with a discrete part, don't create any additional complications from here, but they totally break your $r$ concept).

Comment: @PeeyushKushwaha To be a bit less dismissive towards your line of thinking here, let me put generalities aside for a moment. When you ignore generalities, your $r$ is actually a very important concept in applied probability, because you often are in fact given such an $r$ without being given $f$. $f$ can then be constructed by normalization: set $\tilde{f}(x)=r(x,x_0)$ for all $x$ and some fixed (possible) $x_0$, then construct $f$ by normalizing $\tilde{f}$. Typically the last step is the hardest of the bunch.

Comment: how is the $r$ which you're referring to defined? I think the conversion of that to $f$ is the answer to my question

Comment: @PeeyushKushwaha Often the target distribution is discrete, in which case there is no confusion (although of course in this case $f$ is a PMF, not a PDF). When the target distribution is continuous, $r$ is not actually uniquely defined from the mathematical point of view (essentially because PDFs are non-unique as I mentioned). But from the modeling point of view, it generally arises straightforwardly as "relative probability". For example, a common situation in statistical physics is that $r(x,y)=\exp(-\beta(E(x)-E(y)))$  where $\beta>0$ is a parameter and $E$ represents energy of a state.